# iOS - White screen when testing on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm building an iPhone app, and it works fine when I test it in the simulator. I don't have an iPhone for testing, but my app is configured to be iPhone only, so I'm trying to run it in the iPad. When I run it either in the iPad simulator or the iPad itself all I get is a blank screen, any idea what could be happening?

My app use to be a Universal app, but I switched it to iPhone only to test on the iPad since I don't have an iPhone to test.

Comment: Does your app use a webview? I see this behavior if I try to load a web view that has errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your build settings.

Change "`Targeted Device Family`" from "`iPhone/iPad`" to "`iPhone`" and you will see it in your small iPhone "simulator" on your iPad.

Check my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Changed it, also deleted some settings that were iPad specific on the info.plist. Now it runs in the iPad simulator properly. But in the iPad itself I get this: Couldn't register Equilibrio.Fonyk with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger

Comment: Restart everything. iOS Device and XCode (and also maybe your mac). Make a clean.